# Godot 4: Player movement script not working

Tags: godot

Good morning,

I am new to godot4 and I watched some tutorials to create an rpg. However, after copying a code that I found in several tutorials, it does not work. If you can help me I will be very happy.

Here is my code:

---

```
extends CharacterBody2D

const speed = 100
var current_dir = "none"


func _physics_process(delta):
    player_movement(delta)
    
func player_movement(delta):
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        current_dir = "right"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.x = speed
        velocity.y = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        current_dir = "left"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.x = -speed
        velocity.y = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        current_dir = "down"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.y = speed
        velocity.x = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        current_dir = "up"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.y = -speed
        velocity.x = 0
    else:
        play_anim(0)
        velocity.x = 0
        velocity.y = 0
        
        move_and_slide()
        
func play_anim(movement):
    var dir = current_dir
    var anim = $AnimatedSprite2D
```

There are no errors displayed in my code and I see a lot of people using this script to make the character move but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: The `ui_x` input actions use the arrows only I think. At which node you have put the script?

Comment: The script is put on the player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code is exactly indented as you posted it. Then the error is the indentation of your move_and_slide call. It is part of your else block, so it is not called in the other cases. (The ones, the character should move).

Simple fix: Remove a tab in front of the move_and_slide and it should work:

```
func player_movement(delta):   
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        current_dir = "right"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.x = speed
        velocity.y = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        current_dir = "left"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.x = -speed
        velocity.y = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        current_dir = "down"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.y = speed
        velocity.x = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        current_dir = "up"
        play_anim(1)
        velocity.y = -speed
        velocity.x = 0
    else:
        play_anim(0)
        velocity.x = 0
        velocity.y = 0
        
    move_and_slide()
```